# Com criar uma searchbar sem o ícone de seta no canto esquerdo?

Tags: java, android

Preciso criar uma toolbar com uma searchview que funcione como nas duas primeiras imagens: Quando essa searchview se abrir ela precisa se sobrepor à imagem(logo) e se extender por toda a toolbar.

Se no meu menu eu uso  app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" a sobreposicão da imagem acontece, mas uma seta é exibida no lado esquerdo da searchview, como na terceira imagem.

Se eu uso apenas app:showAsAction="always" a seta não aparece, mas a view onde o logo vai ficar é apenas empurrada para o canto (quarta imagem). Alguma maneira de obter o resultado mostrado nas duas primeiras imagens: logo sendo sobreposto e sem a seta no canto esquerdo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já tentou `app:iconifiedByDefault="false"` e `app:searchIcon="@null"` ?

Comment: Tentei aqui e não funcionou não, mas apontou uma caminho. Vou continuar tentando.

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando a barra de ferramentas v7, você pode remover este botão com este código:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

você pode ler android [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) e [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) para mais informações. Também [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545139/android-back-button-in-the-title-bar) questão pode ajudar